# Strange result when checking if an ip address is in a network with netaddr

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip-address, subnet

When I run the following code in Python 2.7 I get true for all of these checks.

```
from netaddr import *
testip = '192.168.2.5'
testnetwork = '192.168.3.0/23'
if testip in IPNetwork(testnetwork):
    print "Logic Fail"
if IPAddress(testip) in IPNetwork(testnetwork):
    print "Logic Fail"
if testip in IPSet([testnetwork]):
    print "Logic Fail"
if IPAddress(testip) in IPSet([testnetwork]):
    print "Logic Fail"
```

Output is:

```
Logic Fail
Logic Fail
Logic Fail
Logic Fail
```

Comment: `192.168.2._` vs `192.168.3._`, one is `.2`, the other `.3`.

Comment: Did you mean `192.168.3.0/24` ?

Comment: Of course. -_-
I was trying to capture 192.168.3.0 and 192.168.4.0 in the one supernet. But of course it drops back to 192.168.2.0/23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a strange result, the CIDR you specified is what used to be called "supernetting", so:

```
192.168.3.0/23
```

Effectively covers

```
192.168.2.1
```

through

```
192.168.3.254
```

giving you around 512 possible addresses to work with
/23 is the same as this network mask

```
255.255.254.0
```

which is where the 3 gets bumped back to 2

To help visualize, you can use an online subnet calculator like http://mxtoolbox.com/subnetcalculator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For `192.168.3.0/23` network the range is:

`192.168.2.1 - 192.168.3.254`

so your IP address `192.168.2.5` falls into this range. Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but given what's specified python code works as expected